# When inserting a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation, how can I easily make its dimension match the slide's dimension?

Tags: video, office-365

I've inserted a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation. How can I make its dimension match the slide's dimension, without having to painfully manually try to match it?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Office 365 PowerPoint online presentations for several months, and I haven't found any built-in solution to match the slide's dimension when inserting a video. One has to manually try to match it.